# How to convert single hg repository to multiple repositories

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

I have a repository with 5 sub-directories.

repo/

```
a/
    file-a
b/
    file-b
c/
    file-c
d/
    file-d
e/
    file-e
```

How can I convert each sub-directory in to different repositories? (Only relevant changesets to the given sub-directory should be converted new repositories)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) and the `--filemap` flag (after making sure that the `convert` extension is enabled in your `~/.hgrc`):

```
$ hg init new-a
$ cat > a-map
rename a .
exclude b
exclude c
...
$ hg convert --filemap a-map old-repo new-a
$ cd new-a
$ hg co tip
```